# Getting wrong plural from calculation

Tags: php

```
$n=21;
$p=$n%10==1 && $n%100!=11 ? 0 : $n%10>=2 && $n%10<=4 && ($n%100<10 || $n%100>=20) ? 1 : 2;
```

why is $p = 2?
it is supposed to be $p = 0!
is it a bug or am I missing something?

I got this from trying to get the plural form for Russian on: http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/gettext/Plural-forms.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

should be this one:

```
$p=($n%10==1 && $n%100!=11) ? 0 : (($n%10>=2 && $n%10<=4 && ($n%100<10 || $n%100>=20)) ? 1 : 2);
```

the error was in missing bracets

Comment: Should have spotted that, mis-read the != leading me down a wrong path. :) +1

Comment: @David Barker, thanks. anyway i didn't even tried to understand this piece of code, only corrected error, so your answer was interesting!

Answer (score 3):

you can see here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php that "It is recommended that you avoid "stacking" ternary expressions. PHP's behaviour when using more than one ternary operator within a single statement is non-obvious". You can see that if you enclose the else part for the first if between ( and ) you will get another result:

```
$p=$n%10==1 && $n%100!=11 ? 0 : ($n%10>=2 && $n%10<=4 && ($n%100<10 || $n%100>=20) ? 1 : 2);
```

Maybe you should consider changing you statement to a "regular" if block, something like:

```
if ($n%10==1 && $n%100!=11) 
{
    $p =0 ;
} 
elseif ($n%10>=2 && $n%10<=4 && ($n%100<10 || $n%100>=20))
{
    $p = 1;
}
else 
{ 
    $p= 2;
}
```

this way being easier to read